# Django pass a filtered query set between class based views

Tags: django, session, export-to-csv, django-class-based-views

I have a Django class based ListView, which is filtered within its get_queryset function, using url parameters from a filter form, that returns an object_list. Now I want to export the filtered content of the ListView by using a button that calls a second class based view for exporting the list to a .csv file.

Both views are not the problem, but how do I get the data from the ListView, after its filtered, to the export view. Tried something with sessions, but did not get that to work. Perhaps it is possible to hand over the filter parameters but I always ran into problems with the request.session cache, which seems not to be available, even if everything necessary is enabled in the settings.

Any ideas for a good approach on this? Everything I read so far about sessions did not help especially with class based views.

Comment: Just pass the same url parameters (and filtering) to the other view. Or you can export in the same view.

Comment: Can you provide a short example for exporting from same view?